# spark executors on mesos are unbalanced when setting role quota

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am going to run spark job on mesos, and I want to limit resource of specified role.

I try to run 5 executors in my job

```
spark-shell \
--master mesos://zk://host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181/mesos \
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
--conf spark.cores.max=5 \
--conf spark.mesos.role=myrole
```

It works well that I can get many resource offers to distribute executors when quota setting is disable.

```
18/01/25 13:35:49 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Received 4 resource offers.
```

If I enable quota setting(http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/quota/), then I always get only 1 resource offer.
[image]

```
18/01/25 13:36:31 DEBUG MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend: Received 1 resource offers.
```

I have no idea what happened there

My environment:

- spark 2.2
- mesos 1.4.1 (master*3, slave*5)
- CentOS 7.3